# Обращение к элементу UI через строку

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте. Сделал в Qt таблицу label'ов 10х10 с именами labelXY. А как мне к ним обратиться, когда я буду проходить в цикле?
Что-то типа ui->label+i+j ?
Типа как jQuery $('label'+x+y)

Неужели вручную в конструкторе занести в массив [10][10] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, используйте QTableWidget или QTableView, первый вариант проще для начала. Зачем вообще делать таблицу из лейблов? Может я и не прав, но помоему это извращение, это C++/Qt а не php, js и им подобные, здесь так нельзя, а для подобных целей существуют готовые классы с таблицами.

Comment: @MorkOFF48, ну просто привык юзать label для простых задач - динамически менять текст например.  
П.С. Использовал просто TextEdit и генерировал таблицу через \t и \n )

Answer (score 2):

К объектам классов, унаследованных от `QObject`, ***можно*** обращаться по имени. Для этого есть методы класса `QObject`:

```
QString objectName() const
void setObjectName(const QString & name)
```

[**`QObject::findChild(const QString & name = QString(), Qt::FindChildOptions options = Qt::FindChildrenRecursively) const`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

> Returns the child of this object that can be cast into type T and that
>   is called name, or 0 if there is no such object.

Пример:
`QLabel *label = parentWidget->findChild<QLabel *>("labelXY");`

В вашем конкретном случае, чтобы обратиться к label'ам из класса формы:

```
for(int row=0; row<10; row++)
{
    for(int col=0; col<10; col++)
    {
        QString labelName = QString("label%1%2").arg(row).arg(col);

        QLabel *label = findChild<QLabel *>(labelName);

        if(label != 0)
        {
            label->setText("New text");
        }
    }
}
```

Также, можно обращаться по имени и к методам объектов:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread, "quit",
                          Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Документация [QMetaObject::invokeMethod()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod)

Comment: только не забыть objectName для каждого label указать явно.